# Download Image File from a cdn URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I am trying to download a file from Following url in Asp.net https://scontent-sit4-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/14333603_1289676231065862_2460190844802989442_n.jpg?oh=f6ccebc305e599e6dcc0bb7c994d8ac4&oe=586F4DD8
Applying this url as src in img tag works fine but i need to save this image in my download folder.

I tried WebClient.Download method, Downloaddata and webrequest methods but they returned 403 forbidden error

Comment: let me know if my answer works. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `WebRequest` like this: 
*(you have to specify your download folder and links accordingly I guess)*

```
string lnk = @"https://scontent-sit4-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/14333603_1289676231065862_2460190844802989442_n.jpg?oh=f6ccebc305e599e6dcc0bb7c994d8ac4&oe=586F4DD8";
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(lnk);
((HttpWebRequest)request).AllowAutoRedirect = true;
((HttpWebRequest)request).UserAgent = @"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
int dataLength;
int bytesRead;
int wroteSoFar = 0;
var response = request.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
using (FileStream oFile = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"img.jpg"), FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
{
    dataLength = (int)response.ContentLength;
    do
    {
        bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        oFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        wroteSoFar += bytesRead;
        //Console.WriteLine($"{(wroteSoFar / 1000).ToString("N0")} KB / {(dataLength / 1000).ToString("N0")} KB");
    }
    while (bytesRead != 0);
}
```

I managed to download it like this.